# Why do I receive an ArgumentError in the Timex library Timex.compare/2 when passing the result from Timex.date/1

Tags: elixir

With Elixir 1.2.4 and using Timex 2.1.4 as a dependency I run the following code:

`Timex.compare(Timex.date({2015, 12, 1}), Timex.date({2016,1,1}))`

Which breaks with the error:

`%ArgumentError{message: "argument error"}`

Yet if I run:

`Timex.compare(Timex.Date.now, Timex.Date.now)`

I receive an expected value (`0` or 'equals').

When I `IO.inspect` the results of my `Timex.date/1` calls I'm seeing the same Date information I get from a Timex.Date.now call [albeit with different dates contained].

I tried a `case ... do` pattern match to see if I was discarding a more meaningful error in the `{:error, term}` return but that did not yield anything different.

This is likely due to my inexperience with Elixir, so what am I missing?

---

Full code:

```
defmodule Elixirlearning do

  n = Timex.date({2015, 12, 1})
  IO.inspect Timex.Date.now
  IO.inspect n
  IO.inspect Timex.compare(Timex.Date.now, Timex.Date.now)
  IO.inspect Timex.compare(Timex.date({2015, 12, 1}), Timex.date({2016,1,1}))

end
```

Output, as produced in **spacemacs alchemist evaluation**:

```
nofile:58: warning: redefining module Elixirlearning
#<Date(2016-04-20)>
#<Date(2015-12-01)>
0
%ArgumentError{message: "argument error"}
```

Just to clarify, this is using the 'alchemist-eval-buffer' option in the `spacemacs` version of emacs on OSX and producing the above output in a new window.

Here's a screenshot of everything I see in case it provides information I don't think of:

[image: screenshot of spacemacs with alchemist]

Comment: What is the call stack when you get the error? Please add the full error to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I've included all that I see (I hope) to hopefully make this easier to answer.

Comment: The fact that you're trying to do this from within spacemacs makes a lot of difference.  I'd post something on the Elixir Lang slack (on the #emacs channel) to see if there's any way to automate the startup of that package.  But I'd guess that probably the answer you got is the best way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

timex is probably not started. You need to ensure it is started:

`Application.ensure_all_started :timex`

> iex(24)> Timex.compare(Timex.date({2015, 12, 1}), Timex.date({2015,
>   12, 2}))
>   ** (ArgumentError) argument error
>       (stdlib) :ets.lookup(:tzdata_current_release, :release_version)
>                lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex:41: Tzdata.ReleaseReader.current_release_from_table/0
>                lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex:13: Tzdata.ReleaseReader.simple_lookup/1
>                lib/tzdata/release_reader.ex:7: Tzdata.ReleaseReader.zone_and_link_list/0
>                lib/tzdata.ex:61: Tzdata.zone_exists?/1
>                lib/timezone/timezone.ex:166: Timex.Timezone.do_get/3
>                lib/timezone/timezone.ex:310: Timex.Timezone.convert/2
>                lib/datetime/datetime.ex:532: Timex.DateTime.to_seconds/3

```
iex(25)> Application.ensure_all_started :timex
```

> {:ok,  [:idna, :mimerl, :certifi, :ssl_verify_fun, :metrics, :hackney,
>   :tzdata,   :gettext, :timex]}

```
iex(29)> Timex.compare(Timex.date({2015, 12, 1}), Timex.date({2015, 12, 2}))
```

> -1

An easy way to ensure that this app is started is to list it as application dependency in mix.exs

Comment: I inserted the code `Application.ensure_all_started :timex` at the top of the module I was running from the buffer and this fixed it.  Thanks.

Comment: I needed this in my migration which made use of Timex.parse. Thanks!